# Multiple features2d.hpp in openCV

Tags: opencv

I was trying to use features2d.hpp functions present in the features2d folder for detecting  some feature of an image. The code was getting crashed while using this header file. When i used the header file with same name from nonfree folder it worked fine. Could anyone figure out why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

It is two different header files with different content.

`features2d.hpp` from `opencv_features2d` contains free algorithms like `FAST`, `ORB`, `FREAK` and different algorithms for feature matching.

`feature2d.hpp` from `opencv_nonfree` contains patented algorithms : `SIFT` and `SURF`.